# file.getParentFile().mkdirs(); creates duplicate folders in osx

Tags: java, macos, file, exception, directory

im currently developing a program designed to work on windows and osx, i have this function to copy a file which works perfectly in windows, but when i try it in osx, i get an IOException: "no such file or directory", i researched a little bit and found that maybe the destination directory didn't exist (although it did exist) so i added these lines:

```
if(!f2.getParentFile().exists())
{
    f2.getParentFile().mkdirs();
}
if(!f2.exists())
{
   f2.createNewFile();
}
```

this seemed to solve the problem, but when i looked for the copied file (located at documents) i couldn´t find it at first, but then i saw that the program actually created a duplicate folder of the one i wanted to save the file into, so i ended up with two folders with the exact same "documents" name, here's the rest of the code:

```
    public static Boolean copyfile(String srFile, String dtFile )
{
    {
          try
          {
          File f1 = new File(srFile);
          File f2 = new File(dtFile);
          if(!f2.getParentFile().exists())
          {
              f2.getParentFile().mkdirs();
          }
          if(!f2.exists())
          {
              f2.createNewFile();
          }
          InputStream in = new FileInputStream(f1);
          OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(f2);

          byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
          int len;
          while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0){
          out.write(buf, 0, len);
          }
          in.close();
          out.close();
          System.out.println("File copied.");
          }
          catch(FileNotFoundException ex){
          System.out.println(ex.getMessage() + " in the specified directory.");
          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(new JFrame(), ex.getMessage());
          return true;
          }
          catch(IOException e){
          System.out.println(e.getMessage());  
          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(new JFrame(), e.getMessage());
          return true;
          }
          }
    return false;
}
```

this obviously not the desired result, what can i do so the program recognizes the folder in which i want to save the file?

UPDATE: i used the ls -B command and it showed the two folders in different languages: "Documents" and "Documentos" even though they both appear as "Documentos" in the finder

Answer (score 2):

> so i ended up with two folders with the exact same "documents" name,

That couldn't have happened. The two directories have (probably very subtly) different names. For example, one could have a trailing space in the name, etc.

Once you figure out what the difference in the names is, it should become pretty clear how to fix the issue.

You can use the following commands to troubleshoot this: 
`ls -B` should show any non-printable characters as `\xxx`. As to trailing spaces etc, try `ls -1 | od -c` and carefully examine the output.

Comment: +1, but also note it could be something really tricky (like a Zero Width Non Joiner, I have no idea how that would wind up in the name but it could :P)

Comment: @Doorknob: `ls -B` will print that as an escape sequence.

Comment: believe me, that's what i thought, but they are exactly the same, i know that's not possible on windows, and im not sure but i think it isnt possible on osx either, but that's why im so stuck, besides, the destination filename comes from a JFileChooser, which i believe should return the exact selected filename

Comment: @MateoArdilaVillegas: Please include the output from both `ls -B` and from `ls -1 | od -c` in your question.

Comment: @NPE it looks like its a language kind of problem, ls -B returned: "Documents" and "Documentos" even though they both show as "Documentos" in the finder

Comment: @MateoArdilaVillegas: This might be relevant: http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/312881-strange-renaming-of-documents-folder.html

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Java 7, try using the java.nio.file package.  The errors, if any, should be much more informative:

```
Path source = Paths.get(srFile);
Path dest = Paths.get(dtFile);
Files.createDirectories(dest.getParent());
Files.copy(source, dest);
```

I recommend you avoid calling the `getMessage()` method of Throwable.  It often provides information that makes no sense except when shown next to the exception class.  So, instead of `println(ex.getMessage())`, use `println(ex)`.  Of course, far more useful than either of those would be `ex.printStackTrace()`.

Comment: thanks, but im getting the same result with the code you provided, it works but leaves me with duplicate folders